# Render fixed size HTML elements, then resize them using CSS?

Tags: css

If I have an SVG element (or any other element), and it has a width of 200px, can I scale it automatically to fit the size of another element? I.e. could i scale it to a width of 70x, keeping aspect ratio?

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  /*What to put here*/

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="position: relative;/* object-fit: scale-down; *//* max-width: 10px; *//* width: 100px; */"><svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="720" height="480" role="img" style="
  object-fit: scale-down;
  ">
          <rect width="720" height="480" fill="transparent"></rect>
          <g transform="translate(70,10)">
            <g>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="440" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="155" x2="155" y1="0" y2="440" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="310" x2="310" y1="0" y2="440" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="465" x2="465" y1="0" y2="440" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="620" x2="620" y1="0" y2="440" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
            </g>
            <g>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="440" y2="440" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="410" y2="410" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="381" y2="381" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="351" y2="351" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="322" y2="322" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="292" y2="292" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="263" y2="263" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="233" y2="233" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="204" y2="204" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="174" y2="174" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="145" y2="145" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="115" y2="115" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="86" y2="86" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="56" y2="56" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
              <line opacity="1" x1="0" x2="620" y1="27" y2="27" stroke="#EDF2F7" stroke-width="1"></line>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(0,440)">
              <g transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="5" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,10) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">01/03/22</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(155,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="5" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,10) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">01/03/22</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(310,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="5" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,10) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">01/03/22</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(465,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="5" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,10) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">01/03/22</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(620,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="5" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,10) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">01/03/22</text>
              </g>
              <line x1="0" x2="620" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1;"></line>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(0,0)">
              <g transform="translate(0,440)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">0
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,410)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">20
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,381)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">40
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,351)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">60
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,322)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">80
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,292)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">100
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,263)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">120
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,233)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">140
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,204)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">160
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,174)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">180
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,145)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">200
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,115)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">220
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,86)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">240
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,56)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">260
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0,27)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x1="0" x2="-5" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(237, 242, 247); stroke-width: 1;"></line><text
                  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(-21,0) rotate(0)"
                  style="fill: rgb(113, 128, 150); font-weight: bold; font-family: Inter, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">280
                  ms</text>
              </g>
              <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="440" style="stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1;"></line>
            </g>
            <path d="M0,201L155,174L310,126L465,202L620,217" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#D6BCFA"></path>
            <g>
              <g transform="translate(620, 217)" style="pointer-events: none;">
                <g>
                  <circle fill="#fff" r="8" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)"></circle>
                  <circle r="3.2" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)" fill="#D6BCFA" fill-opacity="0.35">
                  </circle>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(465, 202)" style="pointer-events: none;">
                <g>
                  <circle fill="#fff" r="8" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)"></circle>
                  <circle r="3.2" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)" fill="#D6BCFA" fill-opacity="0.35">
                  </circle>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(310, 126)" style="pointer-events: none;">
                <g>
                  <circle fill="#fff" r="8" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)"></circle>
                  <circle r="3.2" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)" fill="#D6BCFA" fill-opacity="0.35">
                  </circle>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(155, 174)" style="pointer-events: none;">
                <g>
                  <circle fill="#fff" r="8" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)"></circle>
                  <circle r="3.2" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)" fill="#D6BCFA" fill-opacity="0.35">
                  </circle>
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(0, 201)" style="pointer-events: none;">
                <g>
                  <circle fill="#fff" r="8" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)"></circle>
                  <circle r="3.2" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(192, 169, 225)" fill="#D6BCFA" fill-opacity="0.35">
                  </circle>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe try using padding or something instead of w/h?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can size it to fit another element keeping the aspect ratio. See CSS property `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Hmm. I tried object-fit, but no diff. For reference, I am using an SVG with a fixed size I cannot alter. I basically want to scale it to fit in a div. Doing my head in as it's so basic a requirement

Comment: Would you please share your code or a snippet please?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pebesusaxa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Please share the code **right in the question itself**, not on an external page.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Click "Edit" below your post, then add a snippet using the button that resembles `<>`.